# Validar campos de formulario en django verificando su existencia en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, python, django-forms

Como validar campos de un formulario en django consultando su existencia en la base de datos ( ej.: el ID de un registro )

Answer (score 0):

puedes ponerle al atributo de tu modelo lo siguiente `unique=True`, algo asi:
`id = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)`, con esto django verifica si en la base de datos existe algun objeto creado con este id

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, me parece una buena opción, la probaré, Feliz día, muy agradecido por tu ayuda.

Comment: Leandro , te molesto con lo siguiente: ya probé la opción que me brindaste, pero lo que sucede es que este id está registrado en otra tabla donde guardo los datos de los clientes (tabla 1)y en está otra tabla(tabla 2 ) guardo los datos de pagos y otros, por lo que necesito verificar que el id exista en la tabla (tabla 1). podría dar resultado excepto que en el primer registro que se insertara en la tabla 2 , no lo aceptaría porque aún no existe. no se si me explico . Gracias por tu atención.

Comment: saludos Oscar, tienes una tabla con datos de clientes y en otra tabla los datos de pago y otras informaciones, supongo q esos datos de pago son asociados a cada cliente,es decir, si el identificador del cliente esta en la tabla de pago es q se le pago y si no esta es q todavia no se le ha pago, la pregunta? tu quieres saber si el id de un cliente esta en esa tabla? si es asi puedes hacerlo manual: datos_pago = NombreTabla.objects.all(), for value in datos_pago: if value.id_cliente == id_cliente hacer_algo. o puedes hacer datos_pago = NombreTabla.objects.filter(id_cliente=id_cliente)

Comment: Leandro muchas gracias por tu ayuda, intentaré hacer lo que me indicas, me parece bastante lógico y razonable . Gracias !